# How to check the specific order and rearrange the piece of text?

Tags: java, string

I am processing a "n" number of files. I had to check if a given file has particular sequence of lines (license_reference: and then license_text_file:) in subsequent order. If any text is present between them they need to be placed above "license_reference:" and the next line should be "license_text_file:". I have given an example case below.

If input is

```
Random_text1
Random_text2
Random_text3
license_reference: 
Random_text4
license_text_file: 

or

Random_text1
Random_text2
license_reference: 
Random_text3
Random_text4
license_text_file:
```

Output should be

```
Random_text1
Random_text2
Random_text3
Random_text4
license_reference: 
license_text_file:
```

The function which I have rights now / which I tried is

```
    public static void addALineAtLast(String Stringtoadd, Path path) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        lines.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
        int position = lines.size();
        lines.add(position, Stringtoadd);
        Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    public static void addALineBeforeLast(String Stringtoadd, Path path) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        lines.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
        int position = lines.size();
        lines.add((position-1), Stringtoadd);
        Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }


    public static Path removeALine(File file, String lineContent) throws IOException
    {
        Path p;
        List<String> out = Files.lines(file.toPath())
                .filter(line -> !line.contains(lineContent))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        out.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
        p=  Files.write(file.toPath(), out, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
        return p;
    }

    public static boolean isTextPresent(String givenText, Path path) throws IOException {
        return FileUtils.readFileToString(path.toFile(),(String)null).contains(givenText);
    }
```

Comment: I suggest that you show us the actual/literal text you need to rearrange.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Added

Comment: Still confusing without context. Can do any number of things. If the license strings are constant you can define these to go last, then sort strings alphabetically. If it is about the number in the end, then you could check last letter, check if it is a number, then append all that has no number. If you need to check for text matches and then group this text and sort by the number you could usse regex or again compare all but the last char... it is really unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: What you mean by "I had to check if a given file has particular sequence of lines in same order."
From ur example it look like you want to sort string 1st based char length and then normal sort on same length string??

Comment: Sorry. Can check now on the input and output. It is not about number that is placed there for just for illustration. It is a random text